# Office pro 2007 Product key does not work after recovering from backup

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I had a hard drive failure but backed up the data before it was fixed. When I put the data back on, Office would not work. Is there anyway to find the code from the back up data ?

Answer (score 0):

How did you back up the data? Unless it was a drive image which you can restore, it's extremely unlikely. I believe this information is stored somewhere in the registry.

We use [Magical Jelly Bean Key Finder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/) at the shop to grab the key before a wipe, but it's not possible from the backup data itself (unless you have mad skills on mounting the registry files).

Now the obvious question: why not reuse the code you have from when you first installed it?